# Windows 7 Explorer shortcut for "Replace All"

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I you copy/paste some files into a directory that already contains files with the same name you'll get a confirmation dialog "There is already a file with the same name in this location..."

To replace all files you have to check "Do this for the next N conflicts" and then click on "Copy and Replace".

Is there a keyboard shortcut for this (like there was in XP where you could simply press 'a')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: If I do this it will select 'Skip' (after the tab) instead of 'copy and replace'. I have to press tab three times (is that what you meant?) to get to 'copy and replace' ... but that's not the quick shortcut I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will select the option.

The description has an underlined "D" on "Do this for the next N conflicts."

Comment: @ChrisF your answer just made my day :D

Comment: This will enable the checkbox but what's the shortcut for "Copy and Replace"?

Answer (score 0):

Alt+D checks the box, but you still need to hit Enter.
Pressing "A" was perfect.  I actually work on computers all day, and that extra keystroke is annoying as hell.