# Windows 7 Copy File dialog keyboard accelerators

Tags: windows-7

In Windows XP, when copying/overwriting multiple files, you could press Alt + A to copy/replace all. 
[image: XP]

These keyboard shortcuts don't seem to be available in Windows 7.  I have to press Alt + D then Tab, Tab, Tab, Space to get the same effect with the keyboard.
[image: Win7]

Does anyone know of a keyboard shortcut to press the giant "buttons" on these dialogs?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/101200/windows-7-explorer-shortcut-for-replace-all

Comment: Yeah, its asking the same thing as my question, basically.  And also without a satisfying response.

Comment: An incredibly annoying aspect of Win7 GUI, indeed. In previous versions you could even press "A" to select "Yes", despite there being no "All" button. Why have that kind of forward thinking then scrap it all for Win7...

Comment: "Progress" and "User Anxiety" not satisfying for you? However, there's a remedy: Total Commander! :)

Comment: Unlike previous versions you can right-click the "Copy and Replace" and "Don't Copy" buttons in that dialog and actually perform tasks on the file, from that dialog.  Not sure why you'd want do this, but isn't that 'progress'?  Regardless, I'd guess it has something to do with why there's no direct accelerator keys for them though. ;)

Comment: IMHO (and the opinion of most people who make GUIs for a living), this dialog is a significant improvement.

Comment: Overall, I like the dialog better, too, but I miss the keyboard accelerator to replace all files being copied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After thinking about it some more, I realized I could accomplish this with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Save the following into a script and run it with AutoHotkey.  The key combination is Alt + A.  It simulates pressing `Alt + D`, `Tab`, `Tab`, `Tab`, `Space` when a window titled "Copy File" is active.

**NOTE: The `IfWinActive` function matches partial titles, so if you have this running and the title of the window has "Copy File" in the title, AutoHotkey will send the keys to that window as well.**

```
;alt + a ... do replace all on select file dialog
#IfWinActive Copy File
!a::
    SendInput !d
    SendInput {Tab}
    SendInput {Tab}
    SendInput {Tab}
    SendInput {Space}
    return
```

Comment: Great answer.  I love AutoHotkey.  Don't forget to close out the #IfWinActive section by placing `#IfWinActive` with no arguments on a line by itself after the return statement (assuming you have no other declarations to wrap in the conditional.)