# Windows 7 - Copy and Replace Always

Tags: windows-7, copy-paste

I want to do a Copy and Replace (an overwrite) always when I am copying files from one folder to another. Is there anyway, *anyway* at all that I can ensure that the prompt does not appear saying "Are you sure you want to Copy and Replace".

I have had a look at this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/104908/windows-7-copy-file-dialog-keyboard-accelerators) but any solution without Auto Hot Key is preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think you are going to find a switch in the Registry to control this.

But you have at least two options to improve your user experience :

### Solution A

Install TeraCopy from http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php. It has plenty of options to achieve what you are trying to do, one of them is Resume file copy should you run out of diskspace.

### Solution B

Install Classic Shell from http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/features.html.
It is free and allows you to enable the old dialog box from Windows XP.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a copy.exe of Windows 7 which accepts parameters, if yes, we could at least do a script of it and then make it a shortcut  (link) in Windows 7 and be done with it. Any thoughts along those lines?

Comment: It might be possible to make a small executable that sits in the taskbar, waiting for the Windows 7 Copy File dialog. When it appears the program will automatically click Copy and Replace.